# Using a named range letter for a starting point

Tags: excel, vba, named-ranges

I am using columns R, ES or KE as starting points for different things.
However, I am sure this workbook will develop, as it already has done so and these starting points will change.
I have a fair few instances of these starting points, and would therefore like to make it so I can change these values very quickly, rather than going through all the code.

To do so, I made a named range and called it 'vb_PercentLetter' . This is for the column R starting point. The value of vb_PercentLetter is 'R'
In vba I used it as such:

```
    x = ws1.Range("vb_PercentLetter" & rowCounter).Offset(0, colCounter) * 100
```

however, that does not work
Is it possible for me to use this method, or should I revert to doing something else?

Comment: Is `Range("vb_PercentLetter" & rowCounter)` on `ws1`?

Comment: So `vb_PercentLetter` is a `Range` with the letter "R" entered in it as a value?

Comment: Yes, just the letter R is entered in the named range. The range is looking up on ws1

Comment: Then you don't actually have a named range

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your comment to  Jeeped: "the vb_PercentLetter is literally just the letter R, nothing else, so it isn't assigned to any worksheet"

If this is the case then vb_PercentLetter is actually a Workbook Name and not named Range.  "R" is not a range.

`Names("vb_PercentLetter")` will return `="R"`

Using a Constant Expression will give the desired result

In a Public Code Module

> ```
> Public vb_PercentLetter = "R"
> ```

I prefer to enumerate the columns of each worksheet.  This makes it very easy to maintain the code.

```
Public Enum WSCoumns1
    ws1Percent = 10
    ws1ES = 11
    ws1KE = 12
End Enum
```

[image]

Enum Syntax

> ```
>  ws1.Cells(rowCounter, ws ).Offset(0, colCounter).Offset(0, colCounter) * 100
> ```